# Is it safe to return a const reference obtained from a member map's iterator?

Tags: c++, memory-management, reference

If `_map` is a member of type `std::unordered_map`, is it safe to return **a reference to** `_map.find(k)->second` from a function, or is this undefined behavior (or just bad practice)?

It seems to work as expected, but it feels kind of like returning a reference to a temporary. I'm not sure if this is true, or if there might be other unintended consequences.

```
#include <unordered_map>
class Container
{
public:
    using Key = int; // or something more interesting

    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // | Is it safe to return a reference here? |
    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    const std::string& get(const Key& k) const
    {
        auto it = _map.find(k);
        return it->second;
    }

    void put(const Key& k, const std::string& v) {
        _map.emplace(k, v);
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<Key, std::string> _map;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Container c;
    c.put(42, "something");

    auto str = c.get(42);

    std::cout << "found " << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the node the reference to which is returned is guaranteed to stay in the memory location (check the documentation for the container) or if the map is not modified after the reference is returned, then returning the reference is as safe as returning a reference to any member - it is usually fine but if the object itself goes out of scope the reference to its member (which someone might cache) is also dead

Comment: This is not the case for `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation for [iterator invalidation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Your reference will remain valid until an operation is performed which invalidates the iterator, such as calling `clear` or `insert`. Note that if you used [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead of [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) then the iterator would remain valid until that element was removed from the container.

Answer (score -1):

It is unsafe to return a const reference of local member variable. The local member variable will be freed while out of function scope, and other program can use its memory. There are no other program use the memory of the local member variable, so it work as expected. But it is uncontrollable and unsafe. You should change to like this:

```
std::string get(const Key& k) const
```

Comment: But it doesn't return a reference to a local variable. `it` is a local variable, but it points to elements contained in the map, which don't go out of scope at the end of the function.